# Cleaning Fermenter

Tags: cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cleaning difficult krausen ring off Better Bottle](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1472/cleaning-difficult-krausen-ring-off-better-bottle)

I just finished my first batch of beer from a Brooklyn Brew Kit, and noticed a film in my fermenter.  This film is right below the the bottle opening along the curve of the glass.  My question is what is the safest way to remove this film without scratching the glass?[image]

Answer (score 4):

Fill it with a solution of warm water and PBW, Oxiclean, or another oxygen based cleaner.  Let it soak for a few hours and it should come right off.

Comment: I only ever need about 1 gallon of the solution. I use HOT water and shake the bloody heck out of it. Set it upright to soak the bottom for a bit, seal the top and set it upside down, then set it on the side and rotate it every now and then. I've never had to get the brush out this way. I tend to make my PBW solution on the strong side, though...2.5x - 3.0x stronger than the container says, depending on how nasty the carboy is. Rinse well!

Answer (score 0):

These are designed for 5 gallon Carboys, but there might be a smaller version at your local brew shop or online.

http://www.homebrewstuff.com/carboy-brush.html

I can usually get 95% of my carboy clean with warm soapy water, but I almost always need the bush to get it all out.

**Edit**: Per Korz's comment, you should use the angled brush but avoid the soap.

Comment: I find that sticking a shop rag or other smallish bit of cloth in the carboy with some PBW or OxyClean and some warm water does wonders for getting the gunk out.

Answer (score 0):

I fill mine with hot water and add half a cup of oxi-clean. stir it up really well (oxi-clean doesn't dissolve all that easily). I leave mine soaking over night. Empty it and spray with warm water. I have brushes but I rarely pull them out, and I use my glass for primary.

Comment: It's likely that the reason your Oxiclean doesn't dissolve is because you're using too much.  I find that 2 Tbsp. is plenty to clean a 6 gal. fermenter that's very grungy.

Comment: Hey thanks Denny! I didn't think about that! I'll try using less and see how it goes. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Matthew is right about the brush (and they do make smaller brushes for 1-gallon jugs), but it is not recommended to use soap on anything that touches your beer.  Soap leaves a film that later will kill your head retention.  Use dishwashing machine detergent in a pinch, but the best for cleaning all brewery equipment is PWB (Powdered Brewery Wash).